# Referencing Controls on main form and a form opened from the main form

Tags: vba, ms-access, controls

I have 2 forms. The first one, in _Load executes several statements such as the one below, storing control references in arrays.

```
Set dateButtonsArray(1) = Forms("DepositsForm").[Date1]
```

Through an event on the first form, I open a second form. In _Load, I do the same thing, e.g.

```
Set detailItemsAmountsArray(1) = Forms("AllocationAnnotationForm").[DI1Amt]
```

The 2nd form's statements do not work (right hand side evaluates to Null).
I have tried a number of things, including ApplicationObject.AllForms, Me... But cannot seem do be able to reference these controls.

PS. I only rarely program in vb. This is a stopgap tool while I work on some web apps for the same place.

Answer (score 1):

If it's evaluating to Null, then it's referencing the control OK, otherwise you'd get an error.

**DI1Amt must actually have a Null value.** Check your data again. Or another reason that you may be getting null is if your form, AllocationAnnotationForm, is set on entering a new record.

Comment: DI1Amt is indeed Null. Yet it is the name of a control on the second form, in the same manner as Date1 on the first form. Record writing or insertion occurs only due to a button click event. Since I have closed and re-opened Access a number of times, I assume that the database is quiescent.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Are you still having problems? If so, can you re-phrase your comment?

Comment: Tom, thanks for your advice. [DI1Amt] was Null, maybe because the form was not yet open. To work around this, I dropped the second form, placing both on one form using a Tab control. Since this app is a workaround solution, I did not want to put more effort into the problem. (vb is not my idea of a profitable branch)